# How can I add a drop shadow effect beneath image views on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, storyboard

I want to add a drop shadow effect underneath my `UIImageView` instances, like in the screenshot below:

[image]

How can I achieve this, either through storyboards or code (Objective-C)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//Drop Shadow
[view.layer setShadowColor: [UIColor grayColor].CGColor];
[view.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8];
[view.layer setShadowRadius:3.0];
[view.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0)];
```

Answer (score 2):

Please Try this once :-

```
UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:view.bounds];
view.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 5.0f);
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
view.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
```

**Explanation :-** 
As seen in the last step there are a few different properties needed when adding a shadow using Core Animation. If your are not familiar with Core Animation don’t worry, just try to focus on the shadow code and not the `CALayer` on the view.

`shadowOffset` is a CGSize representing how far to offset the shadow from the path.

`shadowColor` is the color of the shadow. Shadow colors should always be opaque, because the opacity will be set by the shadowOpacity property. The `shadowColor` property is a `CGColor` not a `UIColor`.

`shadowRadius` is the width of the shadow along the shadow path

`shadowOpacity` determines the opacity of the shadow.

`shadowPath` is probably the most important of the properties. While a shadow can be drawn without specifying a path, for performance reasons you should always specify one. This path tells Core Animation what the opaque regions of the view are, and without it, things slow down severely! It is a `CGPath`, which is most easily created using `UIBezierPath` (iOS only) as shown in step 2.

See more in http://nscookbook.com/2013/01/ios-programming-recipe-10-adding-a-shadow-to-uiview/

Comment: Specifying the shadow path as the view bounds is not a great idea unless the image FILLS the view. For an image which is scaled to FIT the view rather than fill it you want the shadow to drop from the image itself, not the bounding view. Leave the shadow path unspecified.

Answer (score 0):

Those are not lights, but shadow. You can use the layer to draw shadow for UI elements.